# .insertRow() is not working well when <tbody> is empty

Tags: javascript, html, dom

when I try to insert a row to empty `<tbody>` of my table, it added row to `<thead>` that is not empty, but not to `<tbody>`.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <table id="myTable">
    <thead style="background-color: red;">
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
  <br>
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      var row = table.insertRow();
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
      cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

Solution: `<tbody><tr></tr></tbody>`, but it's not very clear...

Answer (score 1):

A table has three parts of: **thead**, **tbody** and **tfoot**. There is no reason your code to insert a new row to tbody, as you want. if you want to add a row in tbody you need to mention it. In your coed make a little change:

```
function myFunction() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  var row = table.insertRow();
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
  cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
}
```

Comment: It's working...

Comment: Glad to help ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var table = document.querySelector("#myTable tbody");`
if you want to add a row in tbody you need to mention the exact location like i did with `document.querySelector("#myTable tbody");`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <table id="myTable">
    <thead style="background-color: red;">
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
  <br>
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {

      var table = document.querySelector("#myTable tbody");
        
      var row = table.insertRow();

      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);



      cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
      cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No strict need for an extra ID, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/tBodies exists.

Comment: May be he has many tables. Id will secure him that case atleast. I was also giving him solution with minimum changes to his code.

Comment: So what, this one already has an ID `myTable`.

Comment: How do it with id="myTable" not with two ids?

Comment: edited as you needed.
@Bc.MartinKubovčík

Comment: Is it slower or faster than solution above? I want a fastest WEB app.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/i0f5o8/performance_of_getelementbyid_vs_queryselector/

If you use QuerySelector with an id, it has better performance than getElementById

for the rest part also it is much more quicker than above answer.